# How can I write this query in ZF?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I am trying to write this, query with zf select but without success

```
SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE id IN (Select subscriber_id From gs_relations Where group_id=55)
```

I was trying with ssomething like this:

```
$gs_relations = new GSRelations();
$part = gs_relations->select()->from('gs_relations',subscriber_id')->where("group_id=$group_id");
$select = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
return $select->where('id IN ('.$part->__toString().')');
```

Anybody can help me to solve the problem!?

Comment: +1, I don't understand why real questions never get voted up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$gs_relations = new GSRelations();
$part = $gs_relations->select()->from('gs_relations','subscriber_id')->where('group_id = ?',$group_id);
$select = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->from('subscribers')->where('id in (' . $part->__toString() . ')');
return $select;
```

`print_r($select->__toString());`

Output:

```
SELECT `subscribers`.* FROM `subscribers` WHERE (id in (SELECT `gs_relations`.`subscriber_id` FROM `gs_relations` WHERE (group_id = 55)))
```

Do let me know how it goes, I used the below code for testing, but did not test executing the actual query as I have no such data structures:

```
$groupId = 55;
$part = $this->db->select()->from('gs_relations','subscriber_id')->where('group_id = ?',$groupId);
$select = $this->db->select()->from('subscribers')->where('id in (' . $part->__toString() . ')');
print_r($select->__toString());
```

Comment: Yeap it is, but I wrote few queries that actually was forking, but u know how it is when simply it ain't going...

Tnx for help anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$groupId = 55;
$part = $gs_relations->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)->from('gs_relations','subscriber_id')->where('group_id = ?', $groupId);
$select = $gs_relations->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)->from('subscribers')->where('id in ?', $part);
```

Comment: +1 - I didn't know you could pass a select() to another select()'s placeholder!